# How to modify the content of index.html for ASP.NET Core SpaServices

Tags: reactjs, .net, .net-core, single-page-application

I am using `AspNetCore.SpaServices` and a React application.

I would like to render some Javascript into `index.html` according to .NET environment.

I tried something like this:

```
var staticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
{
    OnPrepareResponse = context =>
    {
        // Only for Index.HTML file
        if (context.File.Name == "index.html") 
        {
            var response = context.Context.Response;
            var str = "This is your new content";
            var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(str);
            // modified stream
            var responseData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString);
            var stream = new MemoryStream(responseData);
            // set the response body
            response.Body = stream;
        }
    }
};

app.UseStaticFiles(staticFileOptions);
```

This unfortunately does not work for me.

Is there any way how to modify `index.html` in the middleware?

Comment: Are you looking for server side rendering using NodeJS? Or do you just want to add a small html piece to your response?

Comment: I want to add a small html piece to my response. I want to replace some special characters in my index.html according to some conditions.

Comment: But whatever you change will be gone after the angular app is bootstrapped. The only thing that's relevant to show there is a loading indicator. Why can't you just replace those special characters in your `index.html` directly?

Comment: I want to read some config values from AppSettings.json and put it them into index.html

Comment: @Pieterjan - can you help me please with it? Do you know how to do it?